# Product of Sets

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I have a quick question regarding the interpretation of notation in topology. My notes state:

Let $X:=\Pi_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha$ where A is an indexed set.
My interpretation is that $X=X_{\alpha _1}\times X_{\alpha _2}\times...$ , which in a topological sense would imply what....

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that $A$ is specified to be a *directed* set and not simply an *index* set?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott would it make more sense as an index set? The letter A has not been specified directly in this proposition. However, in previous definitions (of the same notes) it has been presented as a directed set (partially ordered set $(A,\leq)$.

Comment: Sorry: what's the question?

Comment: There’s no reason for it to be a directed set, unless you’re looking at direct or inverse limit systems.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott . I see where you're coming from. Given that A is an index set then, could you please explain how X has been defined? Thanks !

Comment: Will do; hang a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as I suspect, $A$ is simply an index set, $\prod_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ is the set of functions $x:A\to\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}X_\alpha$ such that $x(\alpha)\in X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in A$; for convenience I will write $x_\alpha$ instead of $x(\alpha)$. $A$ can be uncountable, so you shouldn’t try to think of it as a product of the form $X_{\alpha_1}\times X_{\alpha_2}\times\ldots$.

If each $X_\alpha$ is a topological space, the simplest way to define the topology is to start with the projection maps

$$\pi_\alpha:X\to X_\alpha:x\mapsto x_\alpha\;;$$

then the product topology on $X$ is the one generated by the subbase

$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A}\left\{\pi_\alpha^{-1}[U]:U\text{ is open in }X_\alpha\right\}\;.$$

In other words, the product topology has as a base sets of the form

$$\bigcap_{\alpha\in F}\pi_\alpha^{-1}[U_\alpha]\;,$$

where $F$ is any finite subset of $A$, and $U_\alpha$ is an open set in $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in F$.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help Brian. I appreciate your time and patience.

Comment: @eXtremiity: My pleasure; topology is still my favorite field.